# Southern Dialect: Word for a time of day?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, dialects, southern-white-vernacular-english

I remember reading a story somewhere that a Southerner wrote about one of his life experiences. He mentioned that in the region he lived there was a time of day that cooled off a large amount in less than ten minutes, and the effect was so remarkable that they had a word for it.

I'm writing something now, and am looking for that word and the region to which it applies. I searched for the article and could not find it. I searched for regional words relating to times of the day, and still could not find it. I have no idea where I would look for such a thing (I've never found it in any of the web sites claiming to have 'accurate' information on the Southern dialect). Does anybody know the word I am looking for, or an information source in which I might be able to find it?

Comment: Sundown  evening

Comment: Thanks. I think I remember him using that word now. I couldn't find the article or region usage on a web search, but I guess usage of the word just isn't widespread enough to make it into any discussions about any of the Southern dialects. 

I reckon the regional usage is (or was) mostly limited to the hotter, drier areas of Texas, as the lack of moisture in the air would cause the heat to rapidly dissipate as the sun set.

Comment: There seems to be a general lack of information on Southern idioms in general. Trying to find the meaning of one is a commonly seen question on here.

Comment: I can't tell if the comment from @Kris satsfied this query or not. I'm from the Texas panhandle, but this didn't really ring any bells for me. I'll try to remember to run it by my parents. Your description made me think about the _dry line_, a regional (southern great plains and West Texas, mostly) meteorological phenomena created by the push-and-pull between moist gulf air and dry air inland. Here's an interesting article about it from a storm-chaser's perspective: https://stormtrack.org/library/forecast/dryline.htm

Comment: I think it has something to do with with the dry climate. If moisture suddenly flooded the air, then it would be hot and humid all evening. Thanks for the dryline information though. It's interesting.

Comment: I've lived in the south all my life and I don't remember it ever doing this at any particular time of day unless you are way up in a mountain holler when the sun goes down behind the mountain. Temperatures can then drop somewhat quickly in certain weather due to thermal inversion. My elder relatives didn't give a name to it that I can remember aside from the commonly used "sundown."

Comment: golden hour? I heard this being used with photography. It's a little time before the Sunset and the lighting will be perfect for taking photographs.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what happens in Arkansas, which can be similar to Texas.

The wide stretches of Arkansas prairie (west of the White River bottom (Des Arc, Hazen, Stuttgart, Arkansas)), when under a baking sun, does become hot as a frying pan. Creeks do spread through the prairie. The creeks are a low spot and will have big trees. They hold the shade and the cool temperatures.

When the sun starts to set, the temperatures quickly try to equalize and the cooler air rushes out. The same thing happens in the wide-open fields of the Mississippi delta, if you are near a broad tree line with a creek. The breeze will be so stiff that it will blow your hair, move your clothes and send you running after your hat. It is a sudden cool-off and the wind will moan around my Grandmother's house.

We call it 'The Evening Breeze'. Not sure that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native Texan. We just say "dusk" for the *time of day* that the temperature might drop significantly. Or "nightfall".

Answer (score -2):

https://ggweather.com/winds.html

> **Norther** A cold strong northerly wind in the Southern Plains of the
>   United States, especially in Texas, which results in a drastic drop in
>   air temperatures.  Also called a **Blue Norther**.  (Glossary of Weather
>   and Climate)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Norther_(weather)

> **A Blue Norther**, also known as a **Texas Norther**, is a fast moving cold
>   front marked by a rapid drop in temperature, strong winds, and dark
>   blue or "black" skies. The cold front originates from the north, hence
>   the "norther,", and **can send temperatures plummeting by 20 or 30
>   degrees in merely minutes.**

Comment: The OP is asking for a time of day, not an incident of cold front.

Comment: @green_ideas The most important feature of the OP's question is the remarkable fast cooling. I stand by the answer as a viable one until OP states otherwise. If nothing else, I found the discovery of the Blue Norther very interesting; perhaps others will as well.

Comment: E. Bagby Atwood, _The Regional Vocabulary of Texas_ (192) has this item on _norther_: "**North wind.** The most dramatic weather phenomenon in Texas (aside from an occasional tornado) is the sudden, sharp wind from the north which can reduce temperatures many degrees in a few hours or even minutes. This is universally known as a _norther_, although many informants make such distinctions as _blue norther_, _wet norther_, and _dry norther_. _Blue norther_ may imply rain (as does _wet norther_); however, it ordinarily means an unusually cold or severe norther, often accompanied by dark clouds."

Comment: I've felt it happen a few times and it's an outstanding sensation.. until it starts pouring cold rain in buckets.  It doesn't happen every day, though, and certainly not at a consistent time.